# Generate Random Test Data with ORDER BY NEWID() , include duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to select random rows from a table for test data.  There may be times I need more rows of test data than there are records in the table.  Duplicates are okay.  How do I structure my select so that I can get duplicate rows?

```
CREATE TABLE [Northwind].[dbo].[Persons]
(PersonID int, LastName varchar(255))

INSERT INTO [Northwind].[dbo].[Persons] 
VALUES
(1, 'Smith'), 
(2, 'Jones'),
(3, 'Washington')

SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Persons]  
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

How do I get the Select statement to give me five records in random order, with repeats?  Currently, it only returns three in random order.

I'd like to be able to extend this to get 100 rows or 1000 rows or however many I need.

Comment: There are several solutions here. They are all a little odd because what you are trying to do is rather odd in a relational data world. You could use another table with more rows and join to your table basically creating a cartesian. You could join the table to itself with a cross join. But no matter how you slice it you may end up with some rows duplicated and some rows not returned at all.

Comment: Is there a requirement that duplicates should only be returned if there is insufficient rows to manage it without duplicates?

Comment: It's fine to have rows duplicated and some rows not returned at all.  And I'd like to be able to extend this to get 100 rows or 1000 rows or however many I need.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a Tally Table, which you can then `CROSS JOIN` to your data to produce millions of rows; to then select just the top 5 of...

Comment: You have a few answers here.  Remember to mark one as accepted if any of them meets your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a temp results table and looped through the query and pushed the results into the temp table.

```
declare  @results table(
SSN varchar(10),
Cusip   varchar(10),
...
EndBillingDate  varchar(10))

DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < @trades
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @results 
   Select   ...

 set @cnt = @cnt + 10
END

select * from @results
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a recursive CTE to union enough rows so that they are larger than what you desire.  Then select from that as you have done before.

```
declare
    @desired int = 5,
    @actual int = (select count(*) from persons);

with

    persons as (

        select    personId,
                  lastName,
                  batch = 0
        from      Persons

        union all
        select    personId,
                  lastName,
                  batch = batch + 1
        from      persons
        where     (batch + 1) * @actual < @desired

    )

    select    
    top (@desired) personId, lastName
    from           persons
    order by       newid()
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned. You could instead us a tally table and then get the random rows;

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4) --Repeat for more
SELECT TOP 500 YT.*
FROM Tally T
     CROSS JOIN YourTable YT
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of how you would solve this without ordering all the records, especially multiple times.

One method is to generate random numbers and to use those for looking up values in your data:

```
with n as (
      select rand(checksum(newid())) as r, 1 as n
      union all
      select rand(checksum(newid())) as r, n + 1
      from n
      where n < 10
     ),
     tt as (
      select t.*, lag(tile_end, 1, 0) over (order by tile_end) as tile_start
      from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) * 1.0 / count(*) over () as tile_end
            from t
           ) t
     )
select tt.*, n.r, (select count(*) from n)
from n left join
     tt
     on n.r >= tt.tile_start and n.r < tt.tile_end;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=13848b3728de5a0bc74d564c16333645) is a db<>fiddle.  The `row_number()` does not need to use `order by newid()`.  It can order by a key that has an index -- which makes that component much more efficient.

For more than 100 rows, you will need `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.